# infinite sum of the sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let the function $f(t): [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Any one can help me to caculate the 2 following sums :
$$A(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^kf(t)^k}{(2k)!}$$
and
$$B(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{k+1}f(t)^k}{(2k+1)!} $$

Comment: Hint: Look at the power series expansion of $\cosh w$ and $\sinh w$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how does it help? power of $t$ in $\cosh$ expansion coincides with the factorial term, here is it a half of that

Comment: @gt6989b $\cosh x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!)}$. If $tf(t)\geq 0$, take $x=\sqrt{tf(t)}$, otherwise looking at $\cos$ instead of $\cosh$ may be relevant? (or just working with complex numbers)

Comment: There is no reason to involve a function $f$. Set $x:=t\,f(t)$ and substitute.

Comment: @ClementC. makes sense, did not think about it